# How can I pass a variable to a view from a controller that doesn't have the same url?

Tags: php, html, oop, model-view-controller

I've hit a brick wall. I have the view file  `header.php` that I want to use on all pages of a site. In this file I want to output `$total_items`, the value of which is the same as `$total_items` in my `getTotalItems()` method that I have in a controller (`Items`). This is associated with the model `ItemsModel` with the query `SELECT count(item_id) as total_items FROM items;`.

The problem I am having is that although `localhost/somemvcproject/items/get_total_items` outputs `$total_items` without any problems, any other URL I type will not recognise it or pull it from `ItemsModel`. I understand this is down to the set up of my URL routing e.g. `localhost/somemvcproject/controller/action/param1/param2/param3` etc and that I have not created a controller called header per say. But how can I access `$total_items` (or for that matter any other variable) from `Items` `getTotalItems()` for a view that is essentially unrelated.

The only thing close to a work around I have is loading `ItemsModel` in each controller every time I wish to include header.php otherwise `$total_items` is an 'undefined variable'. But for every page of the site this seems ridiculous.

What I want to be able to do is something like

```
`
    <!--header.php-->
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Items</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header">    
                <?php echo $total_items ?> 
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`

How can I access `$total_items`?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: No framework. Just an experimental nuts and bolts mvc based effort of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call your model query in each controller, wherever you want to fetch `$total_items` OR
You can extend your current controller class with your own controller class, and put your method in your controller class.

As you haven't declared your framework, it's hard to show you with coding example.

Answer (score 0):

you can make request to call controller to fetch data while loading page.
example:

```
     // use document ready function to make call on document load

       $(document).ready(function() 

      //create ajax call

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your work around is the right one. The only thing I would add to it is that you create a `parent controller`, inherited by all your controllers where you calculate the `$total_items` and pass it to the view.

You would then have to make sure that some sort of initialization function is called; this might very well be the `__construct()`.

Something like:

```
abstract class ControllerBase
{
    function __contruct()
    {
        $total_items = getTotalItems();
        // Pass the $total_items to the views as you normally do
    }
}
```

Then each one of your controllers should inherit the base class:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase 
{
    // Do the stuff
}
```

You need to remember though that, if you implement the `__construct()` in your sub-classes, you must call the parent's:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // MyController's own stuff
    }
}
```

This way, by the time your `action` is called, the `$total_items` variable have had already been calculated and made available to the view.